# form_remote_tag select_tag parameter not passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with my form_remote_tag. it did not pass the parameters.Have been trying solutions from the net and from the ones here, but to no avail.

```
<%=form_remote_tag(:url=> {:action=>"showteam"},:update=>"display_div") do -%>   

          <tr>
            <th colspan="2" scope="col">Choose team&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
            <%=select_tag ('team_id',options_for_select(@teams.collect{|t| [t.name,t.id]}))%>
           </td>

           <td><%=submit_tag "Show"%> </td>           
           </td>
          </tr>                   
         </table>
        <%=end_form_tag%>

        <div id="display_div"></div>
```

that is my list.rhtml view. Here's my controller.

```
def showteam      

  @team = params[:team_id]
  $logger.info("#{Time.now} Received rm12 >> #{@team.inspect} >> #{params[:team_id]} #{session[:user_name]} ")
  render(:layout => false)

end
```

SO from the controller, i get nil value for @team.inspect.
is it the .rhtml file?must i do partial? 
Thank u.

Comment: `$logger.info("@team.inspect >> #{@team.inspect} >> params[:team_id].inspect >> #{params[:team_id].inspect} ")` the output `@team.inspect >> nil >> params[:team_id].inspect >> nil`

Comment: could it be because of the html elements?

Comment: i did debug(params) at showteam.rhtml and nothing was sent there. the t.name & t.id came out right on the page. yes i did try with form_tag.its just that can form_tag update a div too like form_remote_tag? thanks.. :)

Comment: its ok.u ve helped :) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i think  i have solved the problem.

It is indeed because of the HTML table tags.
It seems that they have certain order for my codes to work eg so that the params are being passed.

here's the [link](http://www.kickasslabs.com/2009/03/01/invalidauthenticitytoken-forms-tables-and-rails/)  for more details.

Thank u for those who tries to help. ;)